# DrawerLayout + CollapsingToolbar + Fragments; Toolbar won't collapse or show image

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

As the title suggests, I have an activity that has a `FrameLayout` that houses my `Fragments` [I am NOT using a Tabs, just Transactions].  I also have a `NavigationDrawer` and `Toolbar`.  All of these things work fine.

The issue is that I'm trying to add a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to the `Activity` layout and have `RecyclerView` in the `Fragment` scroll and control the collapsing of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

With the setup shown below, I'm able to use the `NavigationDrawer`, see the `Toolbar` and the expanded `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with NO image inside (odd issue there).  I load the `Fragment` into the `FrameLayout` which contains a `RecyclerView` with 10 test views.  This scrolls fine below the CollapsingToolbar but it does not collapse.

### Activity Layout XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/dl_drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/abl_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/ctb_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/the_color"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_dashboard_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@mipmap/the_image"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/overlay_toolbar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_dashboard_fragmentframe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nv_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/overlay_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### Fragment Layout XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_fragment_dashboardhome"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I don't understand why this isn't working and I've run through a lot of documentation and examples with no luck.  Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the layout I was using for the `Toolbar` did not have the correct height value.

### overlay_toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/get_blue"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/actionbar_getblue">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

### Adjustment to overlay_toolbar include call in Activity XML

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/overlay_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

After that single adjustment to the height the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` began working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

app:layout_behavior should be applied to RecyclerView or any other View capable of nested scrolling such as NestedScrollView.

See this tutorial from codepath: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

You can use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" on RecyclerView you have in fragment.

Comment: I removed app:="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" from the FrameLayout in the Activity and added it to the RecyclerLayout in the Fragment with no luck.  I then tried leaving app:="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in the FrameLayout in the Activity and added it to the Fragment RecyclerView.  Unfortunately, both of these resulted in the same, non-scrolling behavior.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html says: app:layout_collapseMode="pin" to ensure that the Toolbar itself remains pinned to the top of the screen while the view collapses. Not sure if that is a problem.  You can check "Creating Parallax Animations" section from https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#creating-parallax-animations

Comment: I discovered the issue, I appreciate your input but I have used all these resources and the fix was due to the Toolbar height value.