# How to hide toolbar when scroll in fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-toolbar

How to hide toolbar when scrolling in my case? I have Activty with drawer and nested fragments. I need hiding toolbar when scrolling in Pages. How do that? Please help me.

P.S: Sorry for my English please.

**Activity layout:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/app_nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"/>
```

**Fragment with TabLayout and ViewPager:**

```xml
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_please_wait"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/layout_no_internet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

**Page fragment:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/layout_please_wait" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/newsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    layout="@layout/layout_news_empty" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    layout="@layout/layout_no_internet" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: The question here looks like it has good example, should work with the one minor fix described in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132908/drawerlayout-collapsingtoolbar-fragments-toolbar-wont-collapse-or-show-ima

Comment: @Daniel Nugent, thx. But this not worked for me. Maybe because I use a ListView in fragment? I just add app:layout_collapseMode="pin", but tihs not halped me :(

Comment: A suggestion. Try to place the tab as in this https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare sample.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` doesn't work with `CoordinatorLayout`. You must use the `RecyclerView`.

This is because the `ListView` doesn't implement interfaces like `NestedScrollingChild` which is essential for the scrolling behavior.

For more detail, open [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30612453/4803633).